# Qt compile error bits/c++config.h not found

Tags: qt, configuration, g++, qt5

I just installed Qt, Qt creator and g++ on the latest version of Mint, and attempted to compile the default hello world project. After configuring a compiler kit I get the following error:

```
bits/c++config.h: No such file or directiry
/usr/include/c++/4.7/utility
```

No surprise there is no such file at that location. It appears this is some sort of config file where you specify what architecture you're compiling for.
What package do I install, or how do I write or generate this config file?

Comment: any progress? I have the same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c++config.h is not in /usr/include, but rather in an architechture-dependent path. What you need is one of the libstdc++ development packages. You have not specified your platform details but my guess is that what you need is `libstdc++6-4.7-dev` as the error message refers to 4.7. See full list of packages containing c++config.h under Ubuntu and Ubuntu-likes [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=c%2b%2bconfig.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any).

I don't know of a specific package search for Mint but the Ubuntu one has hit the nail on the head for me.

edit: ah drat, I only noticed this was 8 months old immediately after I posted the answer. Is this bad?